# Change line in caption [IEEE Access journal template]

Tags: floats, captions, ieeetran

I want to place a multiline caption for a figure using the IEEE Access template.
The template is like this:

```
\Figure[t!](topskip=0pt, botskip=0pt, midskip=0pt){fig1.png}{<caption>\label{fig1}}
```

I have tried using `\\` and `\newline` but they don't do the trick.
Is that possible?

**Edit**: I provide a code snippet

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Text
\Figure[](topskip=0pt,botskip=0pt,midskip=0pt)[width=1\textwidth]{fig1.png}
    {First line\\
     Second line\\
     Third line
     \label{<figure_label>}}
\end{document}
```

And a link to the template: [IEEE Access template](https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-article/authoring-tools-and-templates/ieee-article-templates/templates-for-ieee-access/).
I apologise for any errors as I am very new to this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but I wasn't sure if the changes we made were not distorting the template. Because the multiline caption for figure or tables requires the `caption` package. Your template does not use this package.

Of course it's up to you whether you use it or not.

Add the following code lines to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{ieeeblue}{\color{accessblue}}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{myformat}{\figcapfont{\textbf{#1}\textbf{#2}}}
\captionsetup{labelfont={bf,ieeeblue},labelformat=myformat}
```

Output:

[image]