# Multiline caption for wide figures in IEEE Access Latex Template

Tags: document-classes, ieee-style

[IEEE Access' Latex template](https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-journal-article/authoring-tools-and-templates/ieee-article-templates/templates-for-ieee-access/) uses its own figure class named `\Figure`

```
\Figure[t!](topskip=0pt, botskip=0pt, midskip=0pt){fig1.png}{<caption>\label{fig1}}
```

This command is for wide figures, that is, figures which span two columns. (For column-width figures the syntax `[width=\columnwidth]` is inserted before {fig1.png})

A problem arises when the caption is longer than the width of the printable area of the paper. It extends beyond the page as a single line.

This problem does not occur for column-width figures with long captions. It automatically converts to a multiline.

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474856/185705) provides a workaround but it messes with the font type and the font size.

So, I decided to do my own research and I tried looking into the `ieeeaccess.cls` file (which you can also find [here](https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-journal-article/authoring-tools-and-templates/ieee-article-templates/templates-for-ieee-access/)). But I am a complete noob to .cls files. I have a strong feeling that something is missing in the `ieeeaccess.cls` file under the `Captions` section.

It reads as

```
%%%
%Captions
\def\@IEEEtablestring{table}

\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
% test if is a for a figure or table
\ifx\@captype\@IEEEtablestring%
% if a table, do table caption
\begin{flushleft}
\vspace*{5pt}
{\vss\color{accessblue}\tablecapheadfont #1. \ }{\raggedright\tablecapfont#2\vss}%
\end{flushleft}
\@IEEEtablecaptionsepspace% V1.6 was a hard coded 8pt
% if not a table, format it as a figure
\else
\@IEEEfigurecaptionsepspace% V1.6 was a hard coded 5pt
% 3/2001 use footnotesize, not small; use two nonbreaking spaces, not one
\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\strut{\color{accessblue}\figcapheadfont #1. \ }\raggedright\figcapfont#2\strut}%
%\ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\columnwidth%
\ifdim \xfigwd >\columnwidth%
% if caption is longer than a line, let it wrap around
\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{\color{accessblue}\figcapheadfont #1. \ }}%
\mbox{}\hfill\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}\noindent\raggedright\unhbox\@tempboxa\figcapfont#2\end{tabular}\hfill\mbox{}%
% if caption is shorter than a line,
% allow user to control short figure caption justification (left or center)
\else%
%\ifcenterfigcaptions \hbox to\hsize{\footnotesize\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
%\else 
\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{\color{accessblue}\figcapheadfont #1. \ }}%
%\parbox[t]{\columnwidth}
{\vss\raggedright\noindent\unhbox\@tempboxa\figcapfont#2\vss}%
%\hbox to\hsize{\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
%\fi
\fi\fi\vskip 1pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
```

I sense that there should be a nested `elseif` to check the condition `\ifdim \xfigwd >\textwidth%`.

However, I seem to not find anything regarding `nested` [\ifdim](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/ifdim).

As I stated earlier I am a complete noob to `.cls` files and its syntax. And my observations might very well be wrong.

Does anyone, who is familiar with `.cls` syntax, happen to share the same observations as mine, and hopefully know what can be changed in the `.cls` file to make multiline captions possible for wide figures?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after fiddling around with the `ieeeaccess.cls` file, I found that replacing `\columnwidth` with `\textwidth` allows multiline to appear (magically) for a wide figure as well as a column-width figure.

So, under the `Caption` section, simply replace the line

```
\ifdim \xfigwd >\columnwidth%
```

with

```
\ifdim \xfigwd >\textwidth%
```

Note that I still am unsure why this is works (but it does). I leave the technical explanation to the experts.

That being said, it also does not mess the font type and the font size that IEEE Access sets, which is what I wanted.

P.s: If anyone finds this solution incorrect, explains why it is, and provides a sound solution, I will gladly remove mine. (It will still be my preferred solution for the moment:)). And I hope IEEE Access takes note of this problem.

**[UPDATE]**

Works with `\linewidth%` too. Thanks to user @Zarko for that suggestion.

Comment: `\ifdim \xfigwd >\linewidth%`?

Comment: @Zarko Just tested with `\linewidth%`. That also works :).